# Knockout multiple buttons expanding their corresponding div

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, durandal

I am trying to show and hide a div section based on the corresponding buttons that are created through foreach loop. At the moment, whenever I click the button it shows all div sections rather than the one the button is under. I am quite new to knockout and I have spent many hours trying different methods and tutorials to resolve this issue but still unsuccessful.

This is the view section:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div class="firstDiv">
 <!-- ko if: $root.filteredAvailabilities().length > 0 -->
 <!-- ko foreach: $root.filteredAvailabilities -->
 <div class="secondDiv">

  <div class="thirdDiv">

   <div class="fourthDiv">
    <div class="fifthDiv">
     <!-- ko with: Items -->

     <div class="sixthDiv">
      <!-- ko if: !$root.viewPrices() -->
      <input class="actionButton" type="button" data-bind="upperCaseValue: $parents[1].ViewPrices, click: $root.ViewPrices" />
      <!-- /ko -->
      <!-- ko if: $root.viewPrices() -->
       <input class="actionButton" type="button" data-bind="upperCaseValue: $parents[1].HidePrices, click: $root.HidePrices" />
      <!-- /ko -->
     </div>

     <!-- /ko -->
    </div>

    <!-- ko if: $root.viewPrices() -->
    <!-- ko foreach: Rooms -->
    <div class="seventhRoomDiv">
     <table class="roomPriceTable">
      <tr>
       <td><span class="roomPriceTableRoomLabel" data-bind="text: Room.Name"></span></td>
      </tr>
     </table>
    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
   </div>
  </div>

  <!-- ko if: $root.viewPrices() -->
  <div class="eighthBottomDiv">
   <input class="actionButton chooseRoomButton" type="button" data-bind="upperCaseValue: $parent.ChooseRoom, click: $root.ChooseRoom" />
  </div>
  <!-- /ko -->

 </div>
 <!-- /ko -->
 <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

In the view model all its doing is setting viewPrices to true:

```js
  /// <summary>
        /// View the prices.
        /// </summary>
        self.ViewPrices = function ()
        {
           self.viewPrices(true);
        };
```

I just want the corresponding seventhDivRoom to display after I click the button that's attached to it rather than displaying all.

Before expanding:
[image: Before expanding]

After expanding - Expanded all three rather than the second one only:
[image: After expanding - Expanded all three rather than the second one only]

**EDIT**

I have tried using Rafael Companhoni example and apply it to my versions, but I am coming across some difficulties to display the div. I have added

```html
self.ShowRoomPrice = ko.observable(false);
```

to the view model. Then added 
    availability.ShowRoomPrice = false;
to the availability callback which is similar to how you created the observable array. Furthermore I have added

```js
    self.Test = function (availability){
      availability.ShowRoomPrice = !availability.ShowRoomPrice
      model.availability(availability);
    };
```

Finally the view looks like this

```html
<!-- ko if: ShowRoomPrice === true -->                   
<input class="actionButton" type="button" data-bind="upperCaseValue: 'Show / Hide Prices', click: $root.ChooseHotel" />      
<!-- /ko -->
```

It does change the state of ShowRoomPrice between true and false but the div does not appear. Is there something that's still missing?

Comment: Have you tried `<!-- ko if: $root.viewPrices -->` (without the `()`)?

Comment: @Stefan Removing the () has not made any difference. It still displays them all.

Comment: Hmmm, it looks like you are using a single observable ko variable to manage the states of the divs. If this is so, you'll need to make sure each "row" has it's own state variable.

Comment: You should combine all those code snippets into a single snippet or fiddle that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the property 'viewPrices' which is in the root view model to decide if the divs should be rendered. In the example below I've added a simple view model with an observableArray of **FilteredAvailabilty** objects. It demonstrates how you could use each sub-view model 'viewPrices' property in the 'if' binding:

```
var FilteredAvailability = function (viewPrices, items, rooms) {
    var self = this;
    self.viewPrices = ko.observable(viewPrices);
    self.Items = ko.observableArray(items);
    self.Rooms = ko.observableArray(rooms);
}

var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;

    // initialize with some data
    self.filteredAvailabilities = ko.observableArray([
        new FilteredAvailability(true, items, rooms), 
        new FilteredAvailability(true, items, rooms),
        new FilteredAvailability(false, items, rooms),
    ]);
};
```

And then in the HTML

```
<div>
    <!-- ko if: filteredAvailabilities().length > 0 -->
    <!-- ko foreach: filteredAvailabilities -->
    <div>
        <!-- ko if: viewPrices -->
            <div>Depends only on each the property 'viewPrices' of each item</div>   
        <!-- /ko -->
    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried using this example and apply it to my versions, but I am coming across some difficulties to display the div. Please see the edit I've made to the original post.